# Unable to identify the weird query syntax

Tags: jquery, html

I am new to jquery. My current project application is built using ajax and jquery.
I found a line in my project with following code

```
$("#p" + this.selected).attr("class", "current");
```

What does it signify?
"#p" signifies the ids 
but what does "#p" + this.selected mean?

Comment: Assuming that `this` refers to a radio or checkbox input, then it will be a boolean value. Therefore you are selecting an element with id of either `ptrue` or `pfalse`. Can you show use all of the code

Comment: post more code so we can explain what `this` refers to

Comment: it is a string concatenation where the expression `"#p" + this.selected` is evaluated to find the id selector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#p" + this.selected).attr("class", "current");
```

In above code, `$("#p" + this.selected)` is a jQuery selector where jQuery selects an element that match `id = "#p" + this.selected` (and `this.selected` is the selected value of current element as this refers to instance of current element for which code getting called)

And `.attr("class", "current");` is to change class attribute of element ( with `id = "#p" + this.selected`) to "current".

For more information please see ["jQuery Selectors"](http://www.w3schools.com/jQuery/jquery_selectors.asp).

Answer (score 1):

It is concatenating the id.

Example

```
var selectedValue="test";

$("#P"+selectedValue)
```

It is equivalent to,

```
$("#Ptest")
```